# Typescript how to compare two arrays of objects have same values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two arrays of objects. The objects have the same structure, just the values can be different. How can I compare their values? I can use a loop, but is there any better option?

One object looks like: {id:1, name:"object"};

Comment: tl;dr If you're not worried about comparing functions, you can simply do `JSON.stringify(objectA) === JSON.stringify(objectB)`.

Comment: By the way, I don't know about Angular, but AngularJS has a special utility function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19055489/15359157